# JSON return null data

Tags: php, json

My php version is 5.2.17 and when i do `json_decode($_GET['getItem'])` return null result!!

```
function getItem(id){
$.getJSON(
    "items.php", 
    { getItem: '{"item": "' + id + '"}'},   
    function(json) {
        $("#"+json.itemName).html(json.itemData);
        }
);
```

items.php

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$jItemArray = json_decode($_GET['getItem']);
var_dump($jItemArray);
die;
```

Comment: `var_dump( json_decode( '{"item": "3"}' ) );` works fine, are you sure the `$_GET['getItem']` is filled?

Comment: what is the value on $_GET['getItem']?

Comment: Have you checked for PHP errors?

Comment: code is fine ... you need to check if $_GET['getItem'] is bringing any value.

Answer (score 2):

I think the params are going to get URI encoded. I would output the value of `$_GET['getItem']` to see what it is. Im guessing you just need to run it through `urldecode` first, before running `json_decode` on it.

With that said... is there a reason you to **send** json instead of standard parameter encoding?

Comment: `urldecode` is automatically called for `$_GET` items, and it doesn't look like there is double encoding going on as he is just passing object to jQuery which handles encoding

Comment: yeah there is a reason, i want result to be in array!

Comment: @Аймен Ахмед: What does that have to do with what youre sending? You can send whatever you want, and then return a json encoded array or hash.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah the problem was in `$_GET['getItem']` i found it's data wasn't correct like that 
`array(1) {
  ["getItem"]=>
  string(18) "{\"item\": \"35\"}"
}`

and by turning of `magic quotes` in `php.ini` it works perfectly

`magic_quotes_gpc = Off`

Thank you all for pointing me out

Answer (score -3):

Your php should be:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($_GET['getItem']);
```